# Find a counterexample for the claim: If $A \subset \Bbb R$ and $m^\ast(A) >0$, then $\exists x \in A$ and $r >0$ such that $(x-r,x+r) \subset A.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Find a counterexample for the following claim: If $A \subset \Bbb R$ and $m^\ast(A) >0$, then $\exists x \in A$ and $r >0$ such that $(x-r,x+r) \subset A.$

The claim here pretty much states that if the outer measure of any interval is greater than zero we can find $r>0$ such that $(x-r,x+r)$ is contained in that interval which would seem reasonable since $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$.

For the counterexample if I let $E = [0,1] \cap \Bbb Q^c$. That is the irrationals in $[0,1]$.  I have that $$m^\ast([0,1]= m^\ast(\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]) + m^\ast([0,1]\cap \Bbb Q^c)$$

which would imply that $m^\ast(E) = 1$ since $m^\ast([0,1])=1$ and since $\Bbb Q \cap [0,1] $ is countable $m^\ast(\Bbb Q \cap [0,1] )= 0$.

How can I use this to find a counterexample for what they stated? I guess I would somehow now show that there isn’t any $r>0$ for which $(x-r,x+r) \subset E$?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/741860/42969

Comment: A [fat Cantor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith–Volterra–Cantor_set) set will do the job

Comment: Your set $E$ contains **no** rational numbers. Is it possible for there to be an open interval $I$ with $I \subset E$?

Comment: @OliverDiaz a fat Cantor set is a much more complicated counterexample than the one OP is asking about.

Comment: @UmbertoP. There cannot be irrationals that would satisfy the requirement?

Comment: @Georgi That is not exactly I am suggesting for you to consider. The question is if it is  possible for there to be an open interval $I \subset E$ if $E$ contains no rational numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there: Take some $x \in E$ and fix some $r>0$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, you will always find some rational number in the interval $(x-r,x+r)$, hence $(x-r,x+r) \not\subseteq E$.

To see this a bit more rigorously, you could think of $x$ as having a infinite decimal expansion $x=0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots$. Since the sequence $x_1=0.a_1,\;x_2=0.a_1a_2,\;x_3=0.a_1a_2a_3,\ldots$ converges to $x$, there exists some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n=0.a_1a_2\ldots a_n \in (x-r,x+r)$, and the number $x_n$ is clearly rational, hence it can not be an element of $E = [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}^c$. This is still just a sketch of a proof, but I hope the idea is clear.

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: I got the idea, but $E$ doesn’t contain any rationals so even if $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, it shouldn’t affect $E$?

Comment: I think you might be confusing something: It is exactly the point that $E$ doesn't contain any rationals. That's where we get the contradiction from. Maybe you could explain your point more clearly, I might be missing what you're saying.

Comment: Yes it seems that I’m confusing something here. If $x \in [0,1] \setminus \Bbb Q$, then cannot I choose small enough irrational $r$ such that $(x-r, x+r) \in [0,1] \setminus \Bbb Q $? This souldn’t contain any rationals since it’s how $E = [0,1] \setminus \Bbb Q $ was constructed.

Comment: Well, first of all, $r$ does not need to be irrational! It is only important that $r>0$. Writing $(x-r,x+r) \in [0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ makes no sense, do you mean $(x-r,x+r) \subseteq[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$? If so, then the interval will certainly contain rational numbers, **because** it is an open interval! Take for instance $x=\sqrt{2}/2$ and $r=0.1$. Then we get $(x-r,x+r)=(\sqrt{2}/2-0.1,\sqrt{2}/2+0.1)$, and you can check that the rational number $0.7$ lies in this interval.